# Compacting wide parquet files direct buffer memory error (suitability of parquet for wide tables)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-blob-storage, parquet

I have a use case where I'm streaming in wide (>50k columns) parquet files which I want to compact for further use.

I've verified that once data is compacted, querying a subset of columns and doing filters is sufficiently fast indicating that parquet is suitable for this task.

However, compaction (spark.read.parquet -> df.coalesce(1) -> df.write.parquet) is problematic even with little data. Namely, I get the following Spark error:

> ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread
>   Thread[FileScanRDD-0,5,main] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer
>   memory

Since I want to write a single parquet out I'm using a 1-executor cluster.

I've tried a lot of Spark and jvm memory options from googling but only thing that seems to help is just using a node with more memory and keeping memory settings as default. However, compacting only 50 parquet files totaling 200MB already requires a 600GB memory node and takes 2 hours. I haven't been able to compact more files at a time since I'm already using the largest node I have access to. The findings are quite surprising and have caused me to doubt the suitability of parquet for this use case.

Has anyone managed to compact wide parquet files with a reasonable amount of resources or has ideas on the memory problems?

I'm using standalone spark 2.3.2 and Azure blob storage.